# My WiFi is not working-Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I can not use my WiFi anymore.  I think the problem started after a certain update. I am linking the diagnosis of my WiFi information here.

Thanks
Ali[enter link description here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23933061/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: If it was working before try reinstalling: `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: I used the --reinstall command and doesn't work.